# Comma delimeted using sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a attributes in a table that have a comma. ex. 123-456,654-321,098-765. Then they are in the same data with the value of 'numbers'.
I am using pl/sql oracle application

```
Output Query
Number | 123-456,654-321,098-765

Assumed Query
Number | 123-456
Number | 654-321
Number | 098-765
```

Comment: Im just using mobile fyi

Comment: Please post table schema and some value in it

Comment: Please show what the data looks like in your source tables, and what you are expecting it to look like when you run your query. Also, please post your current code.

Comment: Never store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of problems...

Comment: First_table varchar2(50), second_table varchar2(1000)

Comment: The i know but that is build in on a project that um using for

Comment: "*I am using pl/sql*" - then show us your stored procedure as well.

Comment: I mean im just using a pl/sql application. Just querying a basic query

Comment: If you don't have a stored procedure (or function) you are not using PL/SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample example how to parse `CSV`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7376)**

```
with temp as
(
    select 'Number' Name , '123-456,654-321,098-765' AS val  from dual
)
select distinct
  t.name, 
  trim(regexp_substr(t.val, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as val
from 
  temp t,
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (
        regexp_replace(t.val, '[^,]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
order by name;
```

Change the `temp CTE` with your query which gave you linear output.